# google script web app trigger depend on time not function

Tags: web, triggers, google-apps-script

I had deployed my script as web app, I have trigger onTime, but trigger dont want execute my script.
How can I get web app and ontime triggers on both host and client sides?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't have a google script execute via time-based triggers and as a web app at the same time.